# How to change the visibility of a ListView inside a Custom Adapter of another ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a `Layout` with two `ListView`'s in Android. The first list view has a custom Adapter with three `TextView`'s . The second `ListView` also has a custom `Adapter` with two `TextView`'s.  At first, the second `ListView` is invisible . On clicking on any `TextView` of the first `ListView`, the second `ListView` should become visible .

In the `customAdapter` class of first list View I have a onclick listener for the `TextView`'s , where I set the visiblity of the second `ListView` to `true` .

The visiblity is correctly changed which I can see in my Logs . But it is not reflected in the UI .

The main Layout with two list views `search_by_bus_id.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/bg_dots" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/listmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listbusid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
            android:scrollingCache="true" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#60000000"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/aboutBus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="458dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" >
        </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListItem for first `ListView` (`list_item3.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="#42BF51"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BusNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:text="124" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Bus1Time"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="4:28pm"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Bus2Time"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Bus1Time"
                android:text="4:28pm" 
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

The adapter class for first LsstView

```
public class BusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bus> implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Bus> objects;
    static BusDetailsAdapter bus_details_adapter;
    static ArrayList<AboutBus> busdetails = new ArrayList<AboutBus>();

    public BusAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Bus> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item3, null);

        }

        Bus i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            TextView busNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BusNo);
            TextView departure1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Bus1Time);
            TextView departure2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Bus2Time);

            if (busNo != null) {
                busNo.setText(i.getBus());
            }
            if (departure1 != null) {
                departure1.setText(i.getDeparture1());
            }
            if (departure2 != null) {
                departure2.setText(i.getDeparture2());
            }

            busNo.setTag(i);

            busNo.setOnClickListener(this);

            departure1.setTag(i);
            departure1.setOnClickListener(this);

            departure2.setTag(i);

            departure2.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        // the view must be returned to our activity
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v2 = (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_by_bus_id, null);

        ListView listView2 = (ListView) v2.findViewById(R.id.aboutBus);

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.BusNo:

            if (listView2 != null) {



                listView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("Visibilty", " " + listView2.getVisibility());
            }

            this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            break;
        case R.id.Bus1Time:

            if (listView2 != null) {

                listView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                Log.d("Visibilty", " " + listView2.getVisibility());
            }

            this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Adapter for listView2 :

```
public class BusDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AboutBus> {

private ArrayList<AboutBus> objects;

public BusDetailsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<AboutBus> objects) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item4, null);
    }


    AboutBus i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {



        TextView Operator = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.Operator);
        TextView Load = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.Load);

        if (Operator != null) {
            Operator.setText(i.getOperator());
        }
        if (Load != null) {
            Load.setText(i.getLoad());
        }

    }

    return v;

}
```

}

ListItem for 2nd ListView (list_item4.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OperatorText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Operator : " 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Operator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/OperatorText"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="dummy" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>


          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LoadText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/OperatorText"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"

            android:text="Load : " 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/Load"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Operator"
             android:layout_below="@+id/Operator"
             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
             android:text="dummy"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Part of Onclick :

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v2 = (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_by_bus_id, null);

    if (BusAdapter.listView2 == null) {

        BusAdapter.listView2 = (ListView) v2
                .findViewById(R.id.aboutBus);
    }


    Bus i = (Bus) v.getTag();

    BusAdapter.busdetails.clear();

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.BusNo:

        AboutBus ab1 = new AboutBus("dummy", "dummy");

        BusAdapter.busdetails.add(ab1);

        BusAdapter.bus_details_adapter = new BusDetailsAdapter(
                getContext(), R.layout.list_item4, BusAdapter.busdetails);

        if (listView2 != null) {

            listView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        break;
    case R.id.Bus1Time:
    .......
    .....continued
```

Comment: You have a "main layout" with two ListViews, but inside your **BusAdapter** onClick method your inflating the same layout with two ListViews, which is... wrong. Your "main layout" is supposedly in an Activity or Fragment, you have to provide a callback and change visibility there, you cannot inflate the same layout.

Comment: Thank you Marko . Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try finding the listview element from the main container layout instead of inflating another layout.

What i mean is , do a findViewById on original view object passed from the activity/fragment to the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the 2nd list View is displayed on top of first list view . I tried that in the main_activity and it is displayed properly . But when I change the visibility in the adapter for 1st listview it is not working

Comment: but where is the associated adapter for specifying the data set for the second Listview? How will it render the data without its adapter

Comment: The data is set :   AboutBus ab2 = new AboutBus(i.getOperator(), i.getLoad2());

   BusAdapter.busdetails.add(ab2);

   BusAdapter.bus_details_adapter = new BusDetailsAdapter(
     getContext(), R.layout.list_item4, BusAdapter.busdetails);

Comment: Can you show me the adapter code for the second listview

Comment: Added the adapter and the list-item for 2nd listView .Please check

Comment: the code for attaching that second list adapter is done where ? In the activity is it , and why is notify data set called for the first list after the click event is performed ?

Comment: Actually Inside the onClick method , I was performing some logic , I removed it before pasting the code here.I have added it now in the last snippent please check . This is a part of that logic where I add the data to the 2nd list view and so the DataSetChanged is called here

Comment: well first i still dont see where you have a done corresponding listview2.setAdapter . Second, call the notifydatasetChanged for second list view adapter , not this.notifydatasetChanged

Comment: listView2.setAdapter(BusAdapter.bus_details_adapter); was already there in my code .  Changed the this,notifyDataSetChanged(); to BusAdapter.bus_details_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); . Still no luck :(

Comment: when and where are you setting the adapter , before the notofy call or after. Does the code above in the Original post have the adapter setting code for listview 2

Comment: I am setting the adapter before the notify call . And the original post here did not have the setting , but my original  code has it . Also 1 more thing is , assume that no data is filled in the list view . But still the color of the  2nd framelayout is  different from that of the 1st layout . So , alteast that color should be shown when I make the listView 2 visible . I have tried this in the main_activity and everything works fine in the main_activity . But only in the adapter the visibility part is not working .

Comment: See i changed my answer , i think i may have understood the problem in your case. Dont inflate another search_by_bus_id.xml. pass the reference of the parent view from the activity to the adapter and then do a findviewbyid on that @RajeshKhetan

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the listview It belongs of layout of activity and your not passing the references of the activity to make visibility or not maybe your try something like this

```
adapter = new (ActivityMain.this, some paramnts)
```

and the adapter takes the reference and change the visibility

Comment: Thank you for your answer . In my main activity I have bus_adapter = new BusAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item3, bus) . Did not understand what you want me to change here .

Comment: your listview are create on xml adapter o in xml of activity ?

Comment: try this, in your activity create a method like this  public static void changeList(){ change visibility of your list  } and in the adapter when click in text call this method like this MainActivity.changeList(); and this all

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare both  FrameLayout of search_by_bus_id.xml and use this in related Java File to disable and enable your ListView. Just keep Visible both LinearLayout and try to change Visibilty of Framelayout in Java file